# Does netlify block php form handling?

Tags: netlify

I switched all of my sites to git and netlify and now none of my contact forms work for my static sites. Does anyone know if they block you from using your own php form handling?

They all worked before. I read some of netlify's info on form handling but it doesn't sound mandatory.  I would like to keep the forms i already have and not use their's.

This is what i have:
(I cant show the contact form because stack overflow is actually picking the html up and reading it. not posting the code. It would only put the words between tags up not the tags themselves... her is a pic though:

[image]

```
    <script>
function submitContactForm(){
  var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
  var name = $('#inputName').val();
  var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
  var phone = $('#inputPhone').val();
  var message = $('#inputMessage').val();
  if(name.trim() == '' ){
    alert('Please enter your name.');
    $('#inputName').focus();
    return false;
  }else if(email.trim() == '' ){
    alert('Please enter your email.');
    $('#inputEmail').focus();
    return false;
  }else if(email.trim() != '' && !reg.test(email)){
    alert('Please enter valid email.');
    $('#inputEmail').focus();
    return false;
  }else if(phone.trim() == '' ){
    alert('Please enter valid phone number.');
    $('#inputPhone').focus();
    return false;
  }else{
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'contactForm.php',
     data:'contactFrmSubmit=1&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&phone='+phone+'&message='+message,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
            $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
        },
        success:function(msg){
            if(msg == 'ok'){
                $('#inputName').val('');
                $('#inputEmail').val('');
                $('#inputPhone').val('');
                $('#inputMessage').val('');
                $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Thanks for contacting us, we\'ll get back to you as soon as possible.</p>');
            }else{
                $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
            }
            $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
        }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

This is what i found on the internet:

```
$("#my-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $form = $(this);
  $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize()).then(function() {
    alert("Thank you!");
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: I did make an edit to your question. People will be more likely to help when you don't request how they answer. :) Good job on the time you took to post an example, so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: haha thanks I'm just tired of the some of the trollish answers I see on here. haha thanks again.

Comment: I get it and it is sad people can't act like they would if they were in person. What you and I want to do is not perpetuate such behavior and lead by example. :) At least, we can try our best and ignore the kooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the submission of the form, the target url is `contactForm.php`.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'contactForm.php'
    .
    .
.....
```

Although Netlify does allow for the running of PHP code at the time of a static site build, there is no php runtime on the CDN, so there will be no php endpoint to process your submission.

This will not be possible.

#### Some Options

Post your form to an outside server (old server) url that will accept your PHP form submission.

Use a third party form API to submit your form.

Use Netlify forms.